# Generating 'weight' column for network analysis

Tags: r, network-analysis

I'm very new to R, so forgive any omissions or errors.
I have a dataframe that contains a series of events (called 'incidents') represented by a column named 'INCIDENT_NUM'. These are strings (ex. 2016111111), and there are multiple cells per incident if there are multiple employees involved in the incident. Employees are represented in their own string column ('EMPL_NO'), and they can be in the column multiple times if they're involved in multiple incidents.

So, the data I have looks like:

| **Incident Number** | EMPL_NO |
| --- | --- |
| 201611111 | EID0012 |
| 201611111 | EID0013 |
| 201611112 | EID0012 |
| 201611112 | EID0013 |
| 201611112 | EID0011 |

What I am aiming to do is see which employees are connected to one another by how many incidents they're co-involved with. Looking at tutorials for network analysis, folks have data that looks like this, which is what I ultimately want:

| **From** | To | **Weight** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EID0011 | EID0012 | 2 |
| EID0012 | EID0013 | 1 |

Is there any easy process for this? My data has thousands of rows, so doing this by hand doesn't feel feasible.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Right now this is a bit too broad since we can't see what you've tried—it would be helpful to see your approach. It looks like you want to calculate degrees. You might want to work with the igraph package, which is well documented and has many tutorials such as [this one](https://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @camille. I agree that it seems like degree and igraph are the right way to go. Looking at the documentation of degree(): 
degree(
  graph,
  v = V(graph),
  mode = c("all", "out", "in", "total"),
  loops = TRUE,
  normalized = FALSE
)

Do you know if 'graph' in this case is just the data frame? Since I don't have a graph made as of yet?

Comment: It might be. You'll need to create a graph from your data. That tutorial and the docs should walk you through that

Comment: This is really too broad of a question for us to provide meaningful help.  It would be better if you could provide some small amount of code to show what you tried.  You are likely to get more help that way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.